# SCNScene from collada file node.geometry is nil

Tags: ios, scenekit, scnnode

The problem is in the title. I need to access the `SCNGeometry` of a `SCNNode` and then edit the `SCNMaterial` collection of the `SCNGeometry` but when I inspect the node almost all its properties are set to `nil` including the `geometry` property. The weird thing is that all the nodes have been loaded from a `.dae` file and are all rendered fine in the scene. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you are retrieving the correct node? What API do you use to do that? What do you see in the SceneKit editor that's built into Xcode?

Comment: In the editor, the model is rendered and there is the correct hierarchy of nodes all with a geometry and a texture applied. In code, to get the node I'm interested in I use `[rootNode childNodeWithName:@"name" recursively:YES];` and then I inspect that returned node's geometry property and it's `nil`. When I set a breakpoint in Xcode and then inspect the object's runtime values the vast majority of them are set to nil. Even the arrays are not empty arrays but nil values.

Comment: I guess that you'll have to provide us with a sample project that shows the issue.